# "Last Week Mon to Sun Auto filter"

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter, weekday

I have a sheet with data which has 2 specific column that has data and on the basis of the filter on the column with dates (last week from Monday to Sunday) needs to be filtered. this activity needs to be done every Monday of the week to create a report to my manager. till now I have been doing it manually but trying to find out ways to do it automatically with the help of vba.

```
Sub Macro1()
Worksheets("OPE Data").Select
With Selection
.Range("B2").Select
Range("B2").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("A1").Value, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Range("B1").Value
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you Sunday and Monday from the previous week.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim sundaydate As Date
Dim mondaydate As Date

sundaydate = Date - (Weekday(Date, vbMonday))
mondaydate = sundaydate - 6
With Worksheets("OPE Data")
    .Range("B2").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & mondaydate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & sundaydate
End With
End Sub
```

I removed your selections, they are not needed.

If you want a cell formula to reference instead of getting the dates in VBA then these will work:

```
TODAY()-(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)) 'Sunday
(TODAY()-(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2))) - 6 'Monday
```

Comment: Sub LstWkFltr()
        
        lastmonday = DateAdd("ww", -1, Date - (Weekday(Date, vbMonday) - 1))
        
        Range("A1").AutoFilter 1, ">=" & Format(lastmonday, "mm/dd/yyyy"), xlAnd, "<=" & Format(lastmonday + 6, "mm/dd/yyyy")

End Sub